# nginx proxy_pass does not take affect

Tags: nginx, flask

I want to deploy an flask app and followed a [tutorial](https://medium.com/faun/deploy-flask-app-with-nginx-using-gunicorn-7fda4f50066a) to get this done using nginx.

As the tutorial states I do as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/app
```

this file contains:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/pi/Desktop/python_scripts/internetdisplay/app.sock;
    }
}
```

A systemd Unit service was created and is succesfully running. This created the app.sock file in the 'internetdisplay' directory. Systemctl status app.service results:

```
● app.service - Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/app.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-11-10 21:16:49 CET; 16h ago
 Main PID: 438 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 2200)
   Memory: 46.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/app.service
           ├─438 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:app.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
           ├─679 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:app.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
           ├─681 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:app.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
           └─682 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:app.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

Nov 10 21:16:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn instance to serve myproject.
Nov 10 21:16:57 raspberrypi gunicorn[438]: [2019-11-10 21:16:57 +0000] [438] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
Nov 10 21:16:57 raspberrypi gunicorn[438]: [2019-11-10 21:16:57 +0000] [438] [INFO] Listening at: unix:app.sock (438)
Nov 10 21:16:57 raspberrypi gunicorn[438]: [2019-11-10 21:16:57 +0000] [438] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Nov 10 21:16:57 raspberrypi gunicorn[438]: [2019-11-10 21:16:57 +0000] [679] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 679
Nov 10 21:16:57 raspberrypi gunicorn[438]: [2019-11-10 21:16:57 +0000] [681] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 681
Nov 10 21:16:57 raspberrypi gunicorn[438]: [2019-11-10 21:16:57 +0000] [682] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 682
```

Then I link to sites-enabled and restart nginx:

```
    sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/app /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
    sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

But surfing to http://localhost leads to an "this site can't be reached" error

Comment: Did you also `sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`?

Comment: Assuming you're entering the URL, `http://localhost` to connect to this:  Have you ensured there's not another nginx config file (possibly a default) which is grabing requests to `localhost` via a `server_name` directive which takes priority.   EDIT: What @DaveW.Smith said!

Comment: Thanks Dave W. Smith and v25, the default file will indeed have had priority. Thank you for this advice. I removed the file.Though now a request to ```http://localhost``` results in 'This site can't be reached'.  
So I guess either Nginx is now not using my app file of there is something wrong with my app.sock...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your location block is not set up correctly to find your resourses.

I assume that this is not the location of your unix socket:

```
/home/tasnuva/work/deployment/src/app.sock
```

Check the following:

1. systemd unit file is creating a socket in the expected location
2. the daemon is indeed running and the socket file exists
3. your nginx config is pointing to the correct socket file.

If none of this tells you anything, please update your question with appropriate error log entries.

Comment: Thanks for your response Andrew! your assumption is correct and I now adjusted my question to with the content of my own app file.

The systemd unit file did create the app.sock file in the expected directory (internetdisplay)

I've run systemctl status app.service and added the result to my question.